# Oracle Left join with a list

Tags: oracle, list, join

I am trying to use a list in my left join and it isn't working, but I'm also not getting an error. It's just not returning data.

Here's the data sample

```
Colors
| Color ID | Color          |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | Red            |
| 2        | Blue           |
| 3        | Green          |
| 4        | Yellow         |


Flags
| Flag     | ColorList|
| -------- | -----    |
| country1 | 1        |
| country2 | 3        |
| country3 | 1,3      |
| country4 | 1,3,4    |
```

My Query

```
select f.flag, f.colorList, c.colorID, c.color
from flags f LEFT JOIN colors c ON to_char(c.colorID) IN f.colorList
```

The output I'm getting - any country that has a list instead of one value isn't returning anything

```
| Flag     | List  | colorID | Color|
| -------- | ----- | ---     | ---  |
| country1 | 1     |1        |red   |
| country2 | 3     |3        |green |
| country3 | 1,3   |
| country4 | 1,3,4 |
```

The output I Want

```
| Flag     | List  | colorID | Color|
| -------- | ----- | ---     | ---  |
| country1 | 1     |1        |red   |
| country2 | 3     |3        |green |
| country3 | 1,3   |1        |red   |
| country3 | 1,3   |3        |green |
| country4 | 1,3,4 |1        |red   |
| country4 | 1,3,4 |3        |green |
| country4 | 1,3,4 |4        |yellow|
```

I tried adding quotes and a couple other variations, but have not had success, but also no errors to help point me in the right direction. I've done a lot of searches to try to find the answers but haven't found anything straightforward.

Comment: What datatype is `flags.colorList`?  I imagine it is a string (CHAR, VARCHAR2, or something similar).  If so, that's not meaningful to Oracle as  "list", and you need to use string manipulation functions to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN` to split your CSV list of colors so that you can get one row for each number in the list, then LEFT JOIN to your colors table

```sql
WITH
    flags (flag, colorlist)
    AS
        (SELECT 'country1', '1' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'country2', '3' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'country3', '1,3' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'country4', '1,3,4' FROM DUAL),
    colors (color_id, color)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 'Red' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'Blue' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 'Green' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 'Yellow' FROM DUAL)
--The Common Table Expressions are used to mock up the sample data. Actual query begins below
SELECT f.flag,
       f.colorlist,
       c.color_id,
       c.color
  FROM flags  f
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE (
           CAST (
               MULTISET (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (colorlist,
                                                   '[^,]+',
                                                   1,
                                                   LEVEL)
                               FROM DUAL
                         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (colorlist, ',') + 1)
                   AS SYS.odciNumberList)) l
       LEFT JOIN colors c ON (l.COLUMN_VALUE = c.color_id);
```